# jQuery/CoffeeScript/Rails doesn't call change() on my input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've got a form with a text field and I'm trying to perform an action whenever the user changes its text:

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, id: "edit_item_title" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

And in my coffeescript file:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#edit_item_title').change ->
    alert("Changed!")
```

For some reason, the `change()` event isn't fired. Just to show that everything else is working, here is some code that DOES work, using `keypress` instead of `change`:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#edit_item_title').keypress ->
    alert("Changed!")
```

I can't use `keypress` because it doesn't take into account when the delete key is pressed, and I can't use `keyup` because it fires whenever the arrow keys are pressed.

I'm quite new to this. Any workaround or idea why this would be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change event fires on input fields when it loses focus, you should be using keyup and detect the keyCode and respond accordingly

```
$(document).ready ->
 skipKeys = [37, 38, 39, 40] # Arrow keys

 $('#edit_item_title').keyup (e)->
  if (skipKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1) # To skip keys
    alert('ok')
```

Answer (score 2):

Change-events don't fire until the `<input>` loses focus. From the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#common-input-element-events):

> **4.10.5.5 Common event behaviors**
>
> [...] The `change` event fires when the value is committed, if that makes sense for the control, or else when the control loses focus.

So just typing something in an `<input type="text">` won't trigger any change-events.

If you need to react to what's being type as it is being typed, then you'll want to use [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), or [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) combined with `@value` and the keyboard event. Which one you use depends on what you need to do.

Demo of the various events: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hrrur2LL/2/